# Workaround for email "Received:" header displaying internal IP address?

Tags: email, database, exim, oracle, spf

I have a database server connected to an application server. The database server contains SQL code that generates automated emails to customers. The database server code creates the email then logs into the application server using the login credentials of one of the users to send the email.

One of my customers is not receiving such emails. Actually, their server receives the email, but rejects it as spam.

I *think* the reason for this is the `Received-SPF` external ip address `xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx` for the application server is **different** than the `Received:` ip address, which is the local IP for the database server. The auto-reply sent back from my customer (name@customercompany.com below) server states

`Diagnostic-Code: smtp; 5.3.0 - Other mail system problem 550-'5.7.1 Client does not have permissions to send as this sender' (delivery attempts: 0)`

and includes the following header information:

```
Received-SPF: Pass (mail.customercompany.com: domain of
  noreply@mycompany.com designates xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx as permitted
  sender) identity=mailfrom; client-ip=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx;
  receiver=mail.customercompany.com;
  envelope-from="noreply@mycompany.com";
  x-sender="noreply@mycompany.com"; x-conformance=spf_only;
  x-record-type="v=spf1"
...
Received: from host3.mycompany.com ([xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx])
  by mail.customercompany.com with ESMTP...SHA384; 02 May 2017 15:40:41 -0400
Received: from [192.168.0.1] (port=17111 helo=mail.mycompany.com)
  by host3.mycompany.com with esmtpa (Exim 4.89)
  (envelope-from <noreply@mycompany.com>)
  id 1d5df6-00023Y-SB
  for name@customercompany.com; Tue, 02 May 2017 12:40:40 -0700
...
X-AntiAbuse: This header was added to track abuse, please include it with any abuse report
X-AntiAbuse: Primary Hostname - host3.mycompany.com
X-AntiAbuse: Original Domain - customercompany.com
X-AntiAbuse: Originator/Caller UID/GID - [47 12] / [47 12]
X-AntiAbuse: Sender Address Domain - mycompany.com
X-Get-Message-Sender-Via: host3.mycompany.com: authenticated_id: noreply@mycompany.com
X-Authenticated-Sender: host3.mycompany.com: noreply@mycompany.com
```

Is it acceptable to include a private (internal) IP address in a SPF record, along with external IP address? Any downside?

Does this look like it might resolve this issue?

Any way to get the email header to report the application server IP address `xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx` instead of the db server internal ip `[192.168.0.1]` appearing in the `Received:` line (without porting the code to the application server)?

I don't want the outside world to see the external IP of the database server.

Comment: The application server is sending the email, not the SQL server. From the looks of it the email has passed the SPF check. `Received-SPF: Pass (mail.company2.com: domain of name@example1.com designates xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx as permitted`. The originating client ip address doesn't need to be included in the SPF record. If it did, SPF would be unworkable. The server that's actually sending the email on behalf of the client needs to be included in the SPF record.

Comment: @joeqwerty - not the server sending the email only on an internal IP.  He should use a relay that is in the SPF record for his domain as pointed out in the answer below.

Comment: My take on it is that the application server is the relay and it is passing the SPF record check. I may be misreading the question though.

Comment: That's exactly right @joeqwerty. The application server has external ip `xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx`. So why does the local IP of the database server appear in the header at all?

Comment: I deleted my answer, because I missed a couple pieces. Your database server appears to be sending properly. I missed the login part that it is sending via the app server. As @joeqwerty mentioned, your SPF is passing. That SMTP error makes me think you may be sending as the customer's domain, and they don't allow receiving those emails from public sources. Can you add if the email is being sent from noreply@company1.com or similar?

Comment: Hmm @CoryKnutson, I not sending as the customer's domain. To simplify things, I've replaced (in my original posting) `example1` and `company1` with `mycompany`, and `example2` and `company2` with `customercompany`. Yes, the email I'm sending from is a `noreply@mycompany.com` email address. Not sure if that matters. Is the internal IP address a red herring (it doesn't matter here)?

Comment: It is unlikely that the Mail server looks at received headers from previous machines. It is not unheard but unlikely. If you want to change that you need to configure your mail server to not add (or remove) the received line, or at least to hide the IPs. It looks however more like a blocking rule on the customer server, I would ask them.